# The "purpousely wrong subtraction" exercise

Tags: java

I am trying solve [this problem on code chef](https://www.codechef.com/problems/CIELAB). I quote it here:

An input contains two integers A and B, such that 1 ≤ B < A ≤ 10000

Print a wrong answer of A-B. Your answer must be a positive integer containing the same number of digits as the correct answer, and exactly one digit must differ from the correct answer. Leading zeros are not allowed. If there are multiple answers satisfying the above conditions, anyone will do.

For instance with input `5858 1234` the output is `1624`. (The correct answer of 5858-1234 is 4624. So, for instance, 2624, 4324, 4623, 4604 and 4629 will be accepted, but 0624, 624, 5858, 4624 and 04624 will be rejected.)

I get the wrong answer to the problem on code even when the output is correct

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Code
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        try{
             Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
             int A = scan.next Int();
             int B = scan.next Int();
             int C;
             if(A>B){
                  C = A-B;
             }else{
                  C = B-A;
             }
             int result = 0;
             int rem = 0;
             int number = 0;
             System.out.print(C);   prints out the initial output
             rem = C%10;
             C = C/10;
             rem = 1;
             number = C*10 + rem;

             **System.out.print(number);** //prints out the result

        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
}
```

The output is correct but then again the code chef is not accepting this solution.

Comment: Please, specify the problem you're trying to solve in the question. Nobody wants to follow the link just to understand your question.

Comment: An input contains 2 integers A and B.
Output-Print a wrong answer of A-B. Your answer must be a positive integer containing the same number of digits as the correct answer, and exactly one digit must differ from the correct answer. Leading zeros are not allowed. If there are multiple answers satisfying the above conditions, anyone will do.
Constraints
1 ≤ B < A ≤ 10000
Sample Input
5858 1234
Sample Output
1624
Output details
The correct answer of 5858-1234 is 4624. So, for instance, 2624, 4324, 4623, 4604 and 4629 will be accepted, but 0624, 624, 5858, 4624 and 04624 will be rejected.

Comment: *"The output is correct but then again the code chef is not accepting this solution."* What is the input and output?

Comment: I see multiple issues with your code already, but it's difficult to say what exactly is wrong without you telling us the input and output. 1: You are allowing input that is invalid according to the constraints. 2. You are silently swallowing exceptions instead of properly handling them. 3. You are printing the initial result before printing the modified result (and you don't print any separator between them.) 4. You are always setting the last digit to 1, which will not modify the result if the last digit is already 1.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you why "code chef" is not accepting it because I don't know this site so I don't know how it compiles code, **but** I can tell you why your code is wrong in general when I compile it on a regular IDE, which is a more usefult information, trust me. I suggest you to write these exercises on an IDE (like I did), because in this case your original solution didn't compile at all.

Here the problems with your code:

- The method is `Scanner.nextInt()`, not `Scanner.next_Int()`;
- There were several lines not properly commented;
- You printed the right and the porpousely wrong solution without separating them, so it is possible the chef readed it as a single number. Replace `System.out.print` with `System.out.println`
- [About the try-catch](https://stackify.com/common-mistakes-handling-java-exception/)...

  - You don't need to declare your main method is throwing java.lang.Exception;
  - Never catch a generic superclass java.lang.Exception. Just, never.
  - If you catch an Exception never leave the catch body empty. It's pointless.
  - The combination "catch Exception + empty catch body" is possibly the worst thing one can do in Java. It just stops your code anytime for any reason with no chance for you to debug it.
- Not an error, but the whole "scan and if" part can be replaced by the single line:
  `int c = Math.abs(scan.nextInt() - scan.nextInt())`
  You don't need `a` and `b` anymore after the calculation, and you can just "remove the minus sign" with the absolute value.

Anyway, here it is how I would solve the problem, with an algorithm that can generate one of every acceptable answers. *(With this I mean that technically to satisfy the request you could always "cheese it", for instance by always changing the last one.)*

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int c = Math.abs(scan.nextInt() - scan.nextInt());      //get sign-less difference
    System.out.println(c);

    ArrayList<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<>();          //creating a list for the digits
    for (int i=c; i>0; i/=10){
        digits.add(i%10);                                   //adding a digit to the list
    }

    int randomIndex = (int) (Math.random()*digits.size());            //picking a random digit index
    int randomDigit = digits.get(randomIndex), newDigit;
    do {
        newDigit = (int) (Math.random()*10);                        //Randomize a new digit
    } while ( newDigit == randomDigit || (randomIndex==0 && randomDigit==0));   //Repeat if it is the same OR if it both the first one and it is 0
    digits.set(randomIndex, newDigit);                              //update the list
    int answer = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < digits.size(); i++ ){
        answer += digits.get(i).intValue() * Math.pow(10,i);        //Revert the list into a integer
    }

    System.out.println(answer);
}
```

Hope I helped!

Comment: Thank you so much and sorry for replying so late